# Needing Credentials of SSH Connection to Private Pod for `pod spec lint` even though Cloned SSH address

Tags: github, ssh, cocoapods

I want to push a new version of a private repo. I have cloned this private repo using `pod clone` and the ssh address for the repo. I can pull and push to the repo successfully. However, If I try to run `pod spec lint` on the repo, it asks for my login credentials.

I have even tried adding an ssh key specifically to this repo but that was ineffectual.

I've been scouring StackOverflow but haven't found anything that seems to relate directly to this or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `--sources` option to avoid the default search path option to GitHub.

From `pod spec lint --help`:

```
The sources from which to pull dependent pods (defaults to
https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git). 
Multiple sources must be comma-delimited.
```

Comment: That did it; thanks! There was another private repo that was needed; comma-delimited did the trick, just like mentioned.